# Prove that either $a\leq x$ or $a\leq -x$ if and only if $a$ is an atom.

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Let $(\mathbb{B},\wedge,\vee,-,0,1,\leq)$ be a Boolean algebra. I wish to prove the following:

> **Claim**: $a$ is an atom if and only if for each $x\in\mathbb{B}$ either $a\leq -x$, or $a\leq x$ (exclusively)

I managed to prove the $\Rightarrow$ part:
Assume that both $a\leq -x$ and $a\leq x$ hold, then $a\leq x\wedge(-x)=0$, so $a\leq 0$, but then $a=0$, so $a$ is not an atom.

I am stuck on proving the second part, can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $a$ is not an atom. As you observed, $a=0$ is no good, so the indirect assumption means that there exists some $b$ with $0<b<a$. 
Clearly, $a\leq b$ is false. 
If $a\leq -b$, then $b=b\wedge a\leq b\wedge -b=0$, a contradiction with $x=b$.

Comment: Actually could you elaborate the $b=b\wedge a\leq b \wedge -b = 0$ line? I am not really sure what you actually did there.

Comment: The definition of $\leq$ is $u\leq v$ iff there exists $w$ such that $u=v\wedge w$. Hence, if this is the case, and $t$ is any element, then $t\wedge u\leq t\wedge v$ (trivial by the axioms of Boolean algebras, the same $w$ is a witness). What I did was using this identity for the inequality $a\leq -b$ by "wedging" both sides with $b$, obtaining $b\wedge a\leq b\wedge -b$.

Comment: You can easily prove the equivalence from the axioms. Your implies mine: $a=w$ is a witness. Try the other direction yourself.

Comment: I don't understand the part $b=b\wedge a$, then sure, this is a contradiction because $b\leq 0$, so $b=0$, so contradiction.

Comment: Again, cf. the definition of smaller... By assumption, $b<a$, so $b=b\wedge a$.

Comment: Aah, now i see it, thanks!