# If for all $x \in B$, either $a \leq x$ or $a \leq x^c$ then $a$ is an atom

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I saw a [related answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031522/prove-that-either-a-leq-x-or-a-leq-x-if-and-only-if-a-is-an-atom), but was unable to figure out what's going on.

> If for all $x \in B$, either $a \leq x$ or $a \leq x^c$ then $a$ is an atom The converse holds as well. $B$ is a boolean algebra.

I was able to prove the converse. Here's how:

Consider $a \land x$, for $x \in B$ where $a$ is an atom. We know that $a \land x \leq a$ by definition of $\land$. Since $a$ is an atom, it is the  minimal element in $B\backslash\{0\}$, so $a \land x \leq a$ means either $a \land x = 0$ or $a \land x = a$. From $a \land x = a$, we get (i) $a \leq x$ (since the g.l.b of $a$ and $x$ is $a)$ and from $a \land x = 0$ we get $a \leq x^c$. Is this correct?

To prove that: if for all $x \in B$, either $a \leq x$ or $a \leq x^c$ then $a$ is an atom, I'm trying to retrace my steps back in the above proof.

If (i) $a \leq x^c$, then $a \land x = 0$ & if (ii) $a \leq x$ then $a \land x = a$. I'm kinda stuck here, it seems.

Comment: Your statement doesn't make sense as written.  Maybe there is a quantifier missing?

Comment: but every $a \in B$ isn't necessarily an atom! What do I understand incorrectly?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: Sorry: I inadvertently interchanged $x$ and $a$. If for **each** $x\in B$ either $a\le x$ or $a\le x^c$, then $a$ is an atom.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I hope it is correct now.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: You’re welcome. It’s almost right: the *for all* $x\in B$ should be inside the *if* clause, not outside it. As you’ve written it, it’s a statement about all $x\in B$. It should be a statement about $a$: if $a$ has a certain property with respect to every member of $B$, then $a$ is an atom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your axioms for Boolean algebras, your proof of the converse may be complete or not.
Perhaps it is convenient to show that $a \wedge x = 0$ implies that $a \leq x'$:
if $a \wedge x = 0$, then
\begin{align}
a 
&= a \wedge 1 = a \wedge 0' = a \wedge (a \wedge x)'\tag{by hypothesis}\\
&= a \wedge (a' \vee x') = (a \wedge a') \vee (a \wedge x')\tag{by distributivity}\\
&= 0 \vee (a \wedge x') = a \wedge x',
\end{align}
whence $a \leq x'$.

For the direct implication, suppose that $a \in B$ is such that for every $x \in B$ we have that $a \leq x$ or $a \leq x'$.
In order to prove that $a$ is an atom, take $b \in B$ such that $0 \leq b < a$.
It is enough to show that $b=0$.
As $b \in B$, it must be $a \leq b$ or $a \leq b'$ (because that's our hypothesis about $a$);
but $b < a$ so $a \nleq b$, and hence $a \leq b'$.
Now it follows that
$$b = b \wedge a \leq b \wedge b' = 0,$$
and therefore $b=0$.
We conclude that $a$ is an atom.